# Mouse Over Event In Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, mouseover

I am unable to reveal the sub menu from the menu

I tried Following methods
1) I tried Mouse over action (obvious one)
2)I tried javascript executor

problem is that the HTML component is loaded only on mouse over so unable to set attribute of the element which is not present in html
I am using java
https://www.milonic.com/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hover action works great, I've written a little testing code you can modify to your needs, here it clicks on the link "About us" in the tab "About Milonic"

What you needed was the `wait` object with the `ExpectedConditions`. It is here to wait for the element in the menu to be clickable.

```
        driver.get("https://www.milonic.com/index.php");


        Actions action = new Actions(driver);

        WebElement hover = driver.findElement(By.id("el136"));      
        action.moveToElement(hover).build().perform();      

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#tbl0 #pTR0 a")));
        element.click();
```

Comment: How did u derive the css locator?

Comment: What do you mean by 'derive' ?

Comment: I wanted to know which tool did u use to get the CSS locator " #tbl0 #pTR0 a" or u did it manually

Answer (score 0):

You can also use javascript executor itself but you need to check css properties and manipulate it using javascript below is an example on how to manipulate it ...Here we have removed the display none property of the element in the CSS

> ((JavascriptExecutor)
>   driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('place the
>   class name')[0].style.display = 'block';");

Check whether it works for you......If not kindly provide us the code

Comment: The javaexecutor(display: block) method does not work because the HTML for the hidden element is not loaded till mouseover event