# Mouse hover is not working correctly in IE11 and firefox

Tags: selenium

I am trying to mouse hover on an element using Action class and then trying to go to other sub element and click, but my mouse hover is pointing some where else.

These are the IE capability which are set for IE and action class code

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();                    
options.enablePersistentHovering();             
options.ignoreZoomSettings();
driverinstance = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);

WebDriverWait myWaitVar = new WebDriverWait(driver, const_waithigh);
myWaitVar.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(element1)));
Actions action = new Actions(driver.get());
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(element1))).click().build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you ignore zoom using `options.ignoreZoomSettings();` IE doesn't calculate the correct position of the element unless your application is fully maximized and zoomed at 100%.

so use the below code once you initialize the driver instance for IE.

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.tagName('html')).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "0"));
```

We are essentially maximizing the window and pressing CTRL+0 to set to the zoom to default level. See if this fixes your issue.

Comment: Can you please help for Firefox as well ?  Below is my firefox code ,         
                                   FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
        firefoxOptions.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
        driverinstance = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);

Comment: For firefox, try using 
`action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(element1))).build().perform();
` and then clicking separately. More detailed here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25358409/7964299